# Closed set in the unit disk

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to formally prove the following:

Let $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ the unit disk and suppose $C \subset \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ a closed set such that $\delta C \subset \mathbb{\Pi}$. Then $C \subset \Pi$. I know this is pretty much intuitive, but I can't figure out a formal proof.

Comment: What is $\Pi$? Some subset of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: with $\Pi$ I simply meant the boundary of the unit disk

Comment: So, $\Bbb S^1$, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C^{0}$ denote the interior of $C$. $\mathbb D =C^{0} \cup (\mathbb D \setminus C)$ because $z \in C\cap \mathbb D  $, $z \notin C^{0}$ implies $z \in \delta (C)$ a contradiction. By connectedness of $\mathbb D $ we get $C\subset \mathbb D $ or $C^{0}=\emptyset$. The former is ruled out because $C$ is compact (and its boundary is then  contained in $\mathbb D$),  so $C^{0}=\emptyset$. This implies that $C$ equals its boundary and hence it lies in the boundary.

Comment: with $C^0$ you mean the interior of $C$?

Comment: @JamesArten Yes. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: also $\mathbb{D} = \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ right?

Comment: $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disk and $\overline {\mathbb D}$ is the closed unit disk. @JamesArten

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \partial C$, such that $x\notin Π$. Then $x\in \overline D$, because $\partial C\subset C\subset \overline D$ ($C$ is closed, so it contains its boundary). Provided that $\overline D$ is closed, we are forced to accept that $x\in (\overline D)^o$, so $x\in \partial C\cap (\overline D)^0$, which means that $\partial C\cap (\overline D)^0\neq \varnothing$ -false, because an open set (such as $(\overline D)^0$ ) does not intersects with its boundary. Consequently $x\in Π$, so $\partial C\subset Π$.